# Laravel query builder order by doesn't work with left join

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Why orderBy is not working, it's not ordering by the nbr_votes in descending order?

```
$all_players = DB::table('example_players')->leftJoin('example_votes', 'example_votes.from_player_id', '=', 'example_players.id')
                                           ->select('example_players.id', 'example_players.name', 'example_players.display_name', 'example_players.role', 'example_players.picture', DB::raw("sum(case example_votes.vote when 'like' then 1 else 0 end) as nbr_votes"))
                                           ->orderBy('nbr_votes', 'desc')                                          
                                           ->groupBy('example_players.id')                                         
                                           ->get();
```

Edit the problem is solved I was confusing the column from_player_id with another one. Thank for your help all :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should Group before Ordering the results.

```
$all_players = DB::table('example_players')->leftJoin('example_votes', 'example_votes.from_player_id', '=', 'example_players.id')
                                            ->select('example_players.id', 'example_players.name', 'example_players.display_name', 'example_players.role', 'example_players.picture', DB::raw("count(example_votes.id) as nbr_votes"))
                                            ->groupBy('example_players.id') 
                                            ->orderBy('nbr_votes', 'desc')                                                                
                                            ->get();
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. However I already tried it and it doesn't change something.

Answer (score 0):

```
$all_players = DB::table('example_players')->leftJoin('example_votes', 'example_votes.from_player_id', '=', 'example_players.id')
                                           ->select('example_players.id', 'example_players.name', 'example_players.display_name', 'example_players.role', 'example_players.picture', DB::raw("count(example_votes.id) as nbr_votes"))
                                           ->groupBy('example_players.id')                                         
                                           ->orderBy(DB::raw("count(examples_votes.id)"),'desc')                                          
                                           ->get();
```

It is because the orderby doesn't know the name you gave the field with as.

Comment: ->orderBy(DB::raw("count(overwatch_votes.id)"), 'desc') changes the order but not by overwatch_votes.id desc

Comment: That is because I don't see the overwatch_votes table in your query? You should first join that table to order on it.

Comment: Thank you however I want to order by count examples_voted.id desc